# Sophos SSL-VPN Assistance

Tags: vpn, sophos, ssl-vpn

Kindly help.I am new to VPN.

SSL-VPN in Sophos was initially configured in such a way that, when I download a ssl-vpn.exe package from the sophos user portal and install it on my windows machine, I find config files under:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Sophos\Sophos SSL VPN Client\config

```
company_name@gateway (ssl-vpn config file)
company_name.ca security certificate 
company_name.user certificate
company_name.user.key certificate.
```

I have no idea about these certificates.
I tried to create a new VPN Profile with firewall rules and downloaded the vpn.exe package from user portal,after installing it on my windows machine, there is just one ssl-vpn config file no certificates are present under C:\Program Files (x86)\Sophos\Sophos SSL VPN Client\config

```
company_name@gateway (ssl-vpn config file)
```

without any certificates.Obviously I cannot connect via the newly created profile. I get this error:

```
 Wed Feb 14 12:21:28 2018 RESOLVE: Cannot resolve host address: test: No     such host is known.
 Wed Feb 14 12:21:28 2018 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1518607288,RESOLVE,,,,,,
```

Comment: You should contact whom ever configure your workstation originally and have them fix it's current configuration.  "Cannot resolve host address: test" - indicates you are attempting to connect to a non-exist host or you have a misconfigured client device since your device no longer is aware of how to resolve the ip address.

Comment: Ask your Administrator for a copy of the certificate

Comment: Its a new vpn-profile, shouldnt sophos automatically generate the certificates?

Comment: “I tried to create a new VPN Profile with firewall rules” Well, that sounds like your problem right there. What exactly did you do? // The certificates and key could be embedded, so that’s not what’s wrong. Indeed, the error message is *quite* clear: “Cannot resolve host address: test: No such host is known”.

Comment: Under Remote Access->SSL->Settings->Override hostname I gave my public ip address. Now it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by entering my public ip address in Override Hostname.That solved the issue.
The new version does not seem to include certificates.